# header()-function not working from within class

Tags: php, xml, browser, header

When I try to create XML from within a class it's not working!

Here's my code:

**This code works / produces XML:**

```
<?php 
  header('Content-Type: application/xml');
  echo "<root><name>sample_name</name></root>";
?>
```

**This next code does NOT work!** (All the browsers (Chrome, Firefox, IE & Opera) show it as HTML.)

```
<?php 
class foo
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        header('Content-Type: application/xml');
        echo "<root><name>sample_name</name></root>";
    }
}
$Test = new foo();
?>
```

Why?

Am I missing something?

There are **NO WHITESPACES** anywhere before or after the code!

**UPDATE: Now it works!**

Comment: And, did your code actually run? How did you verify if not even the XML got written out?

Comment: You need put 2 underscore on the construct

Comment: Sorry! This was a typo! Of course I did NOT forget the second underscore!